# Search box border appears in two colors

Tags: css

I have changed the border color of a search box using     `border-color: #EFEFEF;` but the border still appears in two different colors. How can I make the border a single color?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: This question (still) needs an [mcve] (I've removed the example link as it has died).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to set the `border-style`. By default, the style is `inset`.

Solution: set `border-style:solid;` or use the shorthand property `border:2px solid #EFEFEF;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shorthand property like this..
This will set the `border-color` as well as `border-style`

```
border: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset your input field first.

Put this css into your stylesheet.

```
input
{
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    white-space:normal;
    background:none;
    line-height:1;

    /* Browsers have different default form fonts */
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Arial;
}

// AND HERE YOUR INPUT STYLE
```

Comment: That is overkill. Only the border needs to be reset. The rest of the properties is not necessary at all. The OP didn't ask to have, for instance, the font of the input changed.

Comment: Yes, in this case only border needs to be reset. But reseting whole control will equalize behavior in different browsers. It's more than asked, but for sure, not overkill.

Answer (score 0):

use this because by default it having border.

```
border:1px solid #EFEFEF;
```